# Bootstrap 3 performance -- Screens freezing 5-30 seconds each

Tags: javascript, performance, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

(edit: I did a search before posting but didn't see anything addressing this particular problem, if posts exist please point them out, thanks)

I am developing an internal site using Bootstrap 3 and jQuery 1.11.2. Browser use will be almost exclusively IE with a primary target of IE 11 and the rest (IE 7/8/9 and/or 11 in compatibility mode) dragged forward over the next few months.

The site is essentially a reporting site that pulls data from an Oracle database and generates various HTML reports, usually in HTML table format.

With Bootstrap 3 I am getting severe performance problems. I can't pin down the source of the problems but I do know that the more table rows there are the worse performance is. For example, I just generated a report that has 327 rows, in a table with class="table table-striped table-condensed", and while the screen painted in a few seconds it also froze and would not allow me to scroll for over 20 seconds. But this behavior happens on another report that doesn't use those table classes.

I've run the IE 11 F12 profiler on this and other reports and found RegExp.exec is running upwards of 150,000 to 200,000 times (!!) on these screens. I've previously tried removing all scripts and adding them back in one at a time, and found that adding bootstrap.js is what caused the performance problem.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so what are some general ways I can avoid this? It is rendering the application virtually unusable in spots.

Bootstrap 3 makes developing the screens easy so I can focus on the app functionality, but this is becoming a serious problem. I can deal with a 5-10 second delay, and on one screen I actually implemented a "loading, please wait" modal as a hack and set it to immediately close -- which means it stays open until the browser is finished running the client-side scripts, stops hanging up, and *then* allows the modal to close. So it is a hacky workaround for that report. I'd hate to have to implement such a modal on virtually every screen, especially screens where I may have 20-30 seconds or more delay solely because of Bootstrap.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or bootply duplicating the issue?

Comment: Actually I just figured out the issue, it was interaction between Bootstrap and a new Visual Studio 2013 injected javascript that was running amok. I posted an answer with a link to a site describing exactly the issue I was having. Thanks for the quick response though. :)

Comment: Interesting...I just recently upgraded to 2013. I'm guessing that stuff is part of the 'live' updating of html/css edits?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by the 'live' updating bit but I'm not a VS expert by any stretch. What happens is it silently injects the script you hit F5. I found it when I pulled a view-source to run a static HTML version of the screen. My guess (without looking into it to be honest) that it adds that script after RenderBody() is complete. It happened in both debug and release mode too which I found frustrating. Turning it off caused an immediate and dramatic performance increase in render time -- IE actually is usable almost immediately again!

Comment: Oh I noticed some weird javascript polling my page every second or so...when you edit html or css in VS while the page is open in the browser, the changes are reflected in the browser immediately without refreshing the page. I assumed that's what the weird script was doing.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue is (that was fast!) so I'm posting this in case anyone else runs into it. It turns out the culprit in fact was *not* Bootstrap (or at least not exclusively). I'm developing an MVC app in Visual Studio 2013 which adds a new "feature" that injects a javascript into your output called browserLink. This in turn uses SignalR to establish a communication channel between browsers.

In my case this was wreaking havoc with IE11's layout engine, resulting in the above issue. It appears that it was interfering with Bootstrap 3 somehow causing it to take far longer than necessary to render the page. In fact, it was causing IE 11 to hangup even without Bootstrap 3 turned on.

I had previously used Visual Studio 2012 so this was a surprise when 2013 started injecting this script.

Explanation of the problem and solution is available here: http://sylvester-lee.blogspot.com/2014/03/javascript-or-jquery-perform-very-slowly.html

As recommended there, I disabled browser link from the run/debug menu and it is super-fast now.

If you don't need browserLink (and since I'd never heard of it before, I don't and don't see any reason why I would need it) then my suggestion is to turn it off first and see if that resolves performance issues.

Interestingly I do find it odd that VS2013 ships with Bootstrap as the default layout framework for MVC, and yet injects a javascript that causes performance problems to at least sometimes masquerade as Bootstrap issues.